# android Class not found

Tags: java, android

I am currently facing this issue in my application. please help me out.
activity is regiesterd in manifest file with preceding dot without full package. SetContentView is already set in my activity. any other suggestions ?

Comment: Show your Manifest file.

Comment: post your Manifest & Java file also.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your manifest file has ::

```
<activity android:name ="com.bayview.tapfish.TapFishSplash" />
```

And check PackageName where you put your TapFishSplash.java.